# Is it possible for a maven profile to reference the content of another profile or inherit from another profile?

Tags: maven, profile

**background**

We have to build our app for different environments, the only information about the target environment passed to building pipeline (in a standalone building machine we can't reach) is a property with value, thus

```
mvn package -Dtarget=env1
```

to adapt to different environments, we maintains several profiles activated by different property values in our main pom:

```
<project>
    <groupId>whatever</groupId>
    <artifactId>whatever</artifactId>
    <version>whatever</version>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>app-for-env1</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target</name>
                    <value>env1</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- properties for env1 -->
            </properties>
            <modules>
                <!-- modules for env1 -->
            </modules>
            <dependencyManagement>
                <!-- dependencyManagement for env1 -->
            </dependencyManagement>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>app-for-env2</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target</name>
                    <value>env2</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- properties for env2 -->
            </properties>
            <modules>
                <!-- modules for env2 -->
            </modules>
            <dependencyManagement>
                <!-- dependencyManagement for env2 -->
            </dependencyManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

for now it works for two different runtime environments env1 and env2.

however, we need to support env3 which is very similar to env2, so we have to duplicate the whole app-for-env2 profile to meet the requirement.

so is it possible for a maven profile to reference the content of another profile or inherit from another profile?